# How to create Source from Flow in Akka-stream? (Programming Reactive Systems activity)

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm trying to complete the last assignment (named Reactive Followers) in EFPL - Programming Reactive Systems course at EDx platform.

I was able to fulfil all functions except for the `outgoingFlow`.

It seems to me that I should somehow create a new Source from existing Flow and after some reading, I still haven't realized how to execute the Flow to generate elements for the new Source.

I've tried to use `mapConcat` but with no success.

I think the existing flow is this:

```scala
eventParserFlow
.via(followersFlow)
.filter(p => isNotified(userId)(p))
```

Types for the existing `Flow`s and my tentative do implement `outgoingFlow` can be seen here:

```scala
val eventParserFlow: Flow[ByteString, Event, NotUsed]
val followersFlow: Flow[Event, (Event, Followers), NotUsed]

def outgoingFlow(userId: Int): Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = {
  eventParserFlow
    .via(followersFlow)
    .filter(p => isNotified(userId)(p))
    .mapConcat { case (e, _) => e.render }
  ???
}
```

Can anyone point me to some reading or example of how do I solve similar problem in Akka, please?

Answer (score 0):

just a note - SO is not the best resource for these type of questions. what you should use is [discussion](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:EPFLx+scala-reactiveX+2T2019/discussion/forum/) section in the corresponding edx course

---

regarding your question - i will not give you explicit answer, just few hints.

in akka-streams you can't just create a `Source` out of `Flow`. `Flow` is responsible for transformation, while `Source` creates new events. in your assignment you just forgot to use one of available values.

1. read carefully the comments in `class Server` (not `object`).
2. look closely at `val (inboundSink, broadcastOut) = ...` and try to figure out what each of the `vals` is for and how they relate to each other and to the app itself. it will be helpful to understand what are their types

these hints should be enough to understand how to implement `outgoingFlow`, which is the `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I didn't use the chat because I though, as the course is not in the first offered version, that there wouldn't be users looking at the chats.
I realized that my mistake were trying to use `followersFlow` in place of `broadcastOut`.
Filtering the original source and rendering each Event with mapConcat solved the problem.